# Find package that uses a specific shell command

Tags: rhel, package-management

I believe I have installed multiple packages that use the same shell command to run. I know one of them, but I only vaguely recall installing the other and thus cannot uninstall it. I believe they're causing issues with each other, so I need to uninstall the one that I can't remember. Is there a simple way to find which package is invoked using a certain shell command? This is on RHEL 6.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
yum whatprovides <command>
```

From `man yum`:

```
provides or whatprovides
              Is used to find out which package provides some feature or file.
              Just use a specific name or a file-glob-syntax wildcards to list
              the packages available or installed that provide that feature or
              file.
```

Example:

```
yum whatprovides /bin/ls
coreutils-5.97-34.el5_8.1.x86_64 : The GNU core utilities: a set of tools
                                 : commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /bin/ls



coreutils-5.97-34.el5_8.1.x86_64 : The GNU core utilities: a set of tools
                                 : commonly used in shell scripts
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Other       : Provides-match: /bin/ls
```